# invoke cplex variable from an other function in java

Tags: java, variables, invoke, cplex

How can we invoke cplex (IloCplex cplexx = new IloCplex();)
variable from an other function? because i need to use it frequantly from other functions but i cant do it because it behaves like a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a global variable?

As such:

```
public class MyClass{
    private IloCplex cplexx;

    public MyClass(){
        cplexx = new IloCplex();
    }

    //use cplexx anywhere in MyClass with this.cplexx
}
```

If you want to use the same Cplex make a getter by adding this method to MyClass:

```
public IloCplex getCplexx(){
    return this.cplexx;
}
```

And in other classes you can go like this:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyClass mine = new MyClass();
        mine.getCplexx().solve(); //or some other logic
        System.out.println(mine.getCplexx().getObjValue());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps